# Why is my eth0 getting a dynamic ip when it is configured to be static?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, static-ip

For some reason our office linux box is being assigned an ip address via dhcp and I don't know why.  What is confusing to me is that when I check system-config-network it shows that my eth0 is setup to be a static ip address.  And /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 also shows it is setup to be a static ip, yet it is getting a different ip address than the one specified in the ifcfg-eth0.  Let me know if you have any suggestions on or ideas on where I can look next.

Here are a few details that might help you figure out what an idiot I am :)
Fedora 11
Router in front of this box is running dhcp, starting at 10.42.1.100
This box is configured to be 10.42.1.50 (at least I think it is!), subnet 255.255.255.0 (which is same as the router's lan subnet)
Instead of having the static IP, this box is getting assigned 10.42.1.100.
Here are the ifcfg-eth0 details

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=10.42.1.50
GATEWAY=10.42.1.1
```

Comment: Should have asked before I answered.. it really sounds like NetworkManager is running. You're certain it's killed off?

Comment: Find and check the other two ifcfg-eth0 files under /etc/* and see if they disagree with this file. In my experience, they often do.

Comment: Thanks for the many answers guys. McJeff, yes, the NetworkManager was running and I turned that off.  The problem still persisted after turning it off though.  kmarsh, I think you were probably right, that one of my ifcfg-eth0 files was out-of-sync, but I didn't verify before I used a gui tool to fix.
It has been a while now and I can't remember *exactly* what the tool was but I remember using a GUI program that I found via a (lengthy) google search. It wasn't your standard gnome/kde network config gui though.  Gosh, if I come across the link again I will post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of parameters that I would like to have you amend:

1. *BOOTPROTO=static*
2. Remove the NM_Controlled parameter, or at least comment it out.
   Execute 'service network restart' or '/etc/init.d/network restart' and it should work. Otherwise, you may have to reboot the system and check the relevant log files for further diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

You might try assigning the static IP from the router based on your box's MAC address. That's usually my preferred solution if doing static IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the Avahi daemon is not running.  I have run into this program bringing up interfaces on RHEL5 regardless of what is in the sysconfig-file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just changed the settings file and brought the interface up & down, it may be that there's still a dhcp client running - `ps aux | grep dhcpcd` will give you an idea if that's the case.

If you found a reboot mysteriously made this issue disappear, that was almost certainly the cause :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
#NM_CONTROLLED=no (delete)
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=10.42.1.50
GATEWAY=10.42.1.1




service network restart
chkconfig network on 
chkconfig dhcpd off
```